# why is graphql returning "cannot return null of non-nullable field mutation.createAccnt"

Tags: javascript, graphql

I am creating accounts for new users by this mutation createaccnt but i ended up getting the error above,  have stared at it for days..could someone point where i have messed and correct.
here are the codes.
how i defined my schema

```js
const userSchema = new Schema({
    username:String,
    email:String,
    Password:String,
    addedOn:String

});
```

type definitions

```js
//user type definitio

type User{
    id:ID!,
    username:String!,
    email:String!,
    token:String!,
    Password:String!,
    addedOn:String!,

},
input UserInput{
  email:String!,
  username:String!,
  Password:String!,
  confirmPassword:String!
},
//mutation
type Mutation{
    createAccnt ( userInput:UserInput!) : User!
      }
```

this is how i implemented the mutatiion

```js
//createAccnt 
async createAccnt(parent,{userInput:{
            email,
            username,
            Password,
            confirmPassword
        }},context,info){
            try {
                const {errors,valid}=validateUserInput(
                    email,
                    username,
                    Password,
                    confirmPassword
                );
                //allow for error detection
                if(!valid){
                    throw new UserInputError('errors',{errors})
                };
                //check if user already exist
                const user= await User.findOne({username});
                if(user){
                    throw new UserInputError('username is taken',{
                        errors:{
                            username: 'username is taken'
                        }
                    });
                };
                //hash password
                Password= await bcrypt.hash(Password,12);
                //create a new user object
                const newUsr= new User({
                    email,
                    username,
                    Password,
                    addedOn:new Date().toISOString()
                });

                //save to db
                const res=await newUsr.save();
                //web token
                const token= jwt.sign({
                    id:res.id,
                    email:res.email,
                    usernaem:res.username
                },SECRET_KEY,{expiresIn:'1h'});


                return{
                    ...res._doc,
                    id:res._id,
                    token
                }
            }
             catch (error) {
                throw new Error(error)
            }
```

i have checked throughly through the code ,i can't identify the error.Help identify and correct where possible.

Comment: None of your snippets run. Are you sure you are using raw JavaScript and not some preprocessor/library or even an entirely different technology?

Comment: Checkout the value of ``res._doc``. All keys in the ``User`` type must have a non-nullable value.

Comment: That isn't raw javascript,sorry for that..it's a blend of graphql,Node and express technologies.

Comment: **show used mutation query** - it should contain user fields only .... as [this mutation] result must be User type ... if you asked for any field it should be defined in response ... **if you didn't ask - you should** ;)

Comment: I see your Mutation can not return NULL - it must return a User object (because of the ! at the end of type ```Mutation{ createAccnt ( userInput:UserInput!) : User! }```). I like how you are throwing errors if the data in is not valud, but in that case, do you need the createAccnt Mutation to return NULL? This is why most of these create Mutations functions specify ```:User``` rather than ```:User!```. Does throwing the errors mean you don't have to return a result?

Answer (score 0):

If you are unsure about the handling under the hood.

```
type User{
    id:ID!,
    username:String!,
    email:String!,
    token:String!,
    Password:String!,
    addedOn:String!,

}
```

"!" it's mean can not return  "null" so make sure your code return a User correctly
Above it's mean you must have to return a User object like this.

```js
return {
    id: "some id here",
    username: "some username here",
    email: "some email here",
    token:"token here",
    Password:"pass here",
    addedOn: "date here",

}
```